# How to allow and show extra spaces in html

Tags: javascript, html, css, styles, spaces

If I have a web page with the following text:

'This is some (a bunch of extra spaces in here) test print'.

..it will show as 'This is some test print'.

But is there a way to keep extra spaces in there without using 'nbsp;' for them?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-spacing

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/letter-spacing

Answer (score 2):

Either wrap your text within `<pre>` tags or set the `white-space` property to `pre`

Examples:

```css
p {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<p>This is some                                    test print</p>

<pre>This is some                                  test print</pre>
```

Comment: the white-space:pre; does what I want, but seems to get rid of automatic word wrapping. Like if I have a long sentence with a couple break tags at the end, it will print the whole line horizontally and have side scrolling now. Whereas before, it would wrap according to the browser resolution.

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways

1. Using special character

```
&nbsp;
```

2. Using pre tag as mentioned by @j08692
3. using an inline element with the desired width & height without content

Comment: _"But is there a way to keep extra spaces in there without using 'nbsp;' for them?"_